# Limit Law - Addition of the limits of two functions that DNE

Tags: calculus

I have been quite stumped on the basic limit law for addition.

A problem I am working on has two functions, f(x) and g(x), both approaching a. However, both limits DNE. And I need to come up with possible examples for each function so that the limit of the sum of the two produces a given number. So, my question is, can the limit of the sum of the functions still exist even if individually, the limits of each function DNE?

If anyone could help out, that'd be great.
Thanks

Comment: $f(x)=-x, g(x)=x, -x+x=0$. Take $x\to \infty$.

Comment: Hint: $1+-1 = 0$ and $1/0$ isn't defined.

Comment: I've come up with a possible function for each; however, I am not sure if it follows the limit law. lim x-> a [f(x)+g(x)] = (lim x->a f(x))+ (lim x-> 1 g(x)). If i take the limit of each function seperately, they dne but if i take the limit of the sum of the functions it works. But i guess I am asking if that is allowed?